# Reload tab on navigation in LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a use case where I need to navigate from one salesforce tab to other. I want the tab to which I navigate to reload as I want it to render and per new data which I will be setting in the previous tab.
I have tried using following code but it does not seem to reload the page. It just navigates to the tab.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__navItemPage',
        attributes: {
            apiName: 'tab_api_name'
        },
    });
```

If not complete reload, is there any method which we can invoke on switching/navigating between salesforce tabs as it did not call any of the lifecycle methods while switching tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try window.open(url, "_self");